# Help simplifying a product

Tags: elementary-number-theory, products, elementary-functions

I have this "product of products":
$$\prod_{k=1}^{x}\prod_{i=1}^{k}(x-f(i))$$
Is there any way to simplify it respect to $x$?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The factor $x-f(i)$ appears once for every $k\geq i$, so it equals

$$(x-f(1))^{x}(x-f(2))^{x-1}\cdots(x-f(x-1))^2\cdot(x-f(x))^1.$$

There is no way to simplify it further if $f$ is unknown. One could expand it and find explicit formulas for all terms, but that won't give a simpler expression. Compare with $a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3$ vs. $(a+b)^3$.

Comment: I also got to that conclusion, but that would be expanding the product rather than simplifying it. Thank you